# ng-dropdown-multiselect, does max items break UI

Tags: angularjs

Using this very cool AngularJS control but having a problem with limiting the maximum number of items that can be selected.

http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs.

The documentation is vague at best although there are a lot of properties and features described.  But after several hours of trying combinations of settings I almost got it to work as desired.

I want the dropdown button to display a custom label and show the count of the selected items.  The problem is I can't seem to find any way to have this functionally and also limit the number of selected items the user can click on.

This said, I have not tried to see if it is possible to capture the click event and force the behavior I desire because the control describes the "smartButtonMaxItems" as a property that is intended to do just this, limit the number of selected items.

The JS

```
app.controller('AlphabeticController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window){

var _this = this; // insure correct scope within callBacks to this controller
this.name = "AlphabeticController";

_this.names = [
    { 'pk': 1, 'userName': 'Priscila Gail Hane' },
    { 'pk': 2, 'userName': 'Milford Frank-Duell' },
    { 'pk': 3, 'userName': 'Wilson Albanese' },
    { 'pk': 4, 'userName': 'Aileen Hudec' }
];

// init the selected names collection
_this.oSelectedNames = [];

   // create default alphabetic list of names
this.init = function () {

    // sort names with local characgters (accent inorged)
    _this.oSortedNames = angular.copy(_this.names);
    _this.oSortedNames.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.userName.strength - b.userName.strength || a.userName.localeCompare(b.userName);
    });

};

    this.projectSettings = {
    displayProp: 'userName',
    idProp: 'pk',
    externalIdProp: '',
    styleActive: true,
    showCheckAll: true,
    showUncheckAll: true,
    scrollable: true,
    enableSearch: true,
    keyboardControls: true,
    dynamicTitle: true,
    smartButtonMaxItems: 0,
    smartButtonTextConverter: function (itemText, originalItem) {
        return _this.oSelectedNames.length;
    }
};

this.projectText = {
    buttonDefaultText: _this.oSelectedNames.length + ' Selected Names',
    selectionCount: 0,
    selectionOf: 0,
    searchPlaceholder: 'enter name',
    dynamicButtonTextSuffix: ' Selected Names'
};

}]);
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AlphabeticController as AC" ng-init="AC.init()">

<div ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
     options="AC.oSortedNames"
     selected-model="AC.oSelectedNames"
     translation-texts="AC.projectText"
     extra-settings="AC.projectSettings"
     search-filter="">
</div>

</div>
```

With the value of zero (0) set on the "smartButtonMaxItems" property the dropdown button works correctly but there is no upper limit to the number of items that can be selected.  Whereas, with the "smartButtonMaxItems" set to a value smaller than the names array the control limits the number of items that can be selected by the button no longer shows the count and rather shows the names them selves.

[Demo on Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rfe2ps7s/65/)

Comment: I think I figured it out...  The "smartButtonMaxItems" property limits the numbers of items that can be displayed on the button only.  By setting it to anything other than zero, the button displays the selected items.  If the selected items extends past a desired length the page formatting might be messed up.  This is the solution, truncate the extras.  Also not listed in the documentation is a property "selectionLimit" setting this to my max number of items sets the number of items that can be selected.  It works correctly!

Answer (score 2):

To limit the selection i have added   `selectionLimit: 2` to `this.projectSettings` .
Also i have customized the selection message in the below fiddler . Hope this helps you

Here's [Updated fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rfe2ps7s/79/)

Comment: Yea, I came up with the same answer if you look at my last comment above.  The documentation is really lacking.  Thanks for your answer.